# Return JSONObject with JSONArray not working in Amazon Lambda Java function

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I created one Java lambda function and deploy that function to `Amazon API gateway`.

I want to return `JSONObject` with inner `JSONArray`.

But I got `{ }` empty JSONObject in response.

If I set `jsonobjetc.toString()` in response, That will work perfectly.

But if I return `JSONObject` I will return empty `{} JSON` response.

Am I missing something?

```
JSONObject mainJsonObject;

    @Override
    public Object handleRequest(Object input, Context context) {

        inputHashMap = (LinkedHashMap) input;
        responseJSON = new ResponseJSON();
        mainJsonObject = new JSONObject();

        saveDataToDynamoDB(inputHashMap);

        return mainJsonObject;
    }

    public void saveDataToDynamoDB(LinkedHashMap inHashMap){

        String login_id = (String) inputHashMap.get("login_id");
        String first_name = (String) inputHashMap.get("first_name");
        String last_name = (String) inputHashMap.get("last_name");

        try{
            DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(new AmazonDynamoDBClient());
            Table tableUserDetails = dynamoDB.getTable(USER_PROFILE_TABLE);

            Item userProfileTableItem = new Item().withPrimaryKey("login_id", login_id)
                    .withString("first_name", first_name).withString("last_name", last_name);

            tableUserDetails.putItem(userProfileTableItem);

            mainJsonObject.put("status", "Success");
            mainJsonObject.put("message", "Profile saved successfully.");
            mainJsonObject.put("login_id", login_id);
            mainJsonObject.put("first_name", first_name);
            mainJsonObject.put("last_name", last_name);

        }catch(Exception e){
            try {
                mainJsonObject.put("status", "Failed");
                mainJsonObject.put("message", "Failed to saved profile data.");
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are calling this code from HTTP request of a web service & catch the response result in your application, then your response should be in String format (String representation of JSON object).
After you get the response in String format, then parse the JSON string to JSON Object & do your further logic.